# specify bar width for a single bar

Tags: chart.js

Is it possible to specify the bar width on Chart.js when there is only one bar?

I'm showing years on a bar chart, but there is often only one year (2015), so it's really wide - I want it to be much narrower.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get around by changing this property to a higher value when you have only a bar, for example:

```
//Number - Spacing between each of the X value sets
maxBarThickness: 150
```

Check [here](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html) how to use this option.

Answer (score 0):

I just added null labels if the number of items was below my threshold.

```
    const chartLabels = this.prodChart.chart.config.data.labels;
    if (chartLabels.length < 8) {
      chartLabels.length = 8;
    }
```